# Cycles rendering no speed change with gpu vs cpu

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering, gpu

I have a GeForce GTX760 with 4GB ram.  i7-4790 CPU with 16GB ram.  I am running version 2.78c of blender.  When rendering in cycles there is virtually no speed difference.  When i first got the system about 2 years ago,  there was a huge speed difference in render times.  Has something changed in the newer versions of blender?  What am I missing?

Comment: Have you tried for example this benchmark scene? https://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?239480-2-7x-Cycles-benchmark-(Updated-BMW) Is there still no difference in that? If there is a difference, maybe there is something in your scene that messes things up. How is your tile size set up? If not, do you have the latest drivers? Have you selected the correct compute device in preferences->system?

Comment: changing the tile size make a big difference on the rendering speed; however, blender is crashing if I set to 256 for the tile size.  I did not experience this problem until I updated to blender 2.78c.